# Thunderpush monitoring

Tags: python, notifications, tornado, real-time-updates, sockjs

[Thunderpush](https://github.com/thunderpush/thunderpush) is a Tornado and SockJS based push service. It provides a Beaconpush (beaconpush.com) inspired HTTP API and client.

I'm wondering how I can monitor usage statistics and performances

Answer (score 0):

Inside "examples" folder you have some info, like users connected:
https://github.com/thunderpush/thunderpush/blob/master/examples/apiconsole.html

Comment: those are not usage statistics like sent messages and user activities log

Comment: @manuel-84 For that data type, since you use a specific Client to send messages to connected sockets, you should add loging to those scripts, this is just a lightweight push service